# Remote Control an Isolated Chrome Window?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, remote-control

I need to remote control Chrome on Windows into doing what my application dictates.
Right now, my strategy looks like this:

`APP` > `WebSocket implementation` > `chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=xxxx` > `Remote Debugger` > `Local Contorl Page` > `Custom Events` > `Custom Extension`

Application launches Chrome with Remote Debugger on, connects to remote debugger through WebSockets. A custom extension launches a new Tab with an empty page and implements a simple event. The Application places a string in a textbox and triggers the event. Extension picks up on the event and evals the code from the textarea, then sending back responses either the same way, or through Console messages.

This is a nightmare bandwagon where both processes are loosely interconnected and the likelihood of things going is very up on the scale.

I don't know any other languages besides JS, PHP or SQL. Is there any other approach I can try in the given circumstances? Perhaps some extension exposes the chrome.* API or anything?

Comment: Would Selenium fit your needs? See http://seleniumhq.org/ and http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Comment: What is the goal you're trying to achieve by remote-controlling Chrome?

Comment: I'm working on a desktop program that relies on external web apps. Some of those either have paid APIs or no APIs at all. They are also written in JS, so exec speed is key. I tried every other solution besides Chrome. I need Chrome.